How should we give slugs in all languages in the API?
I have a question.
Laravel How should we give slugs of all languages in a multilingual site? For example, should we have en and es languages, should we give the slugs of these languages in the api?
For example:
"slug_lang": {
    "en": "example-1",
    "es": "ejemplo-1"
},

Is this true?
I tried the slug logic in my spelling

Yes, including the slugs for each language in your API as you've shown is a correct approach.
